# GNOME Brightness Settings problems

Tags: gnome, brightness, settings

Somehow, the "Brightness and Lock" system setting keeps turning my laptop screen off within 30 seconds, unless I hit a key or touch the mouse pad.

I have tried all combinations of Lock, Unlock, and changed lock time from 30 seconds to up to 1 hour, Never, etc. to see if the hardware or software would get my input. I’ve I rebooted the PC multiple times (as in the “you never know” last-resort option) getting the same result: The screen goes blank/black within 30 seconds.

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 and, for unrelated reasons, I had to do it two or three times. Finally, a couple of hours after everything seemed to be working fine, the screen problem started.

Being almost new to Ubuntu, I and have no bag of tricks to resort to. So, any suggestion would be welcome and greatly appreciated.
Thanks much!